# Apache rewrite rule for existing file-system directory

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

The following rewrite rule does not work in the .htaccess file of my doc-root:

```
RewriteRule ^shop/b2b/something(/)?$     https://domain.tld/business [NC,R=301,PT,L]
```

because I really have a file system sub-folder "shop" in my web-servers document root. This folder contains another web-app with its own .htaccess file.

I think the reason for this is in the mod_rewrite documentation:

> Note that mod_rewrite tries to guess whether you have specified a
>   file-system path or a URL-path by checking to see if the first segment
>   of the path exists at the root of the file-system.

Is there any way to disable this check for single rules or in general?

Comment: My guess is you try with `http://www.example.com/shop/b2b/something/PAGE.html` right?  In your RewriteRule, add a `/` before shop.  Here your rewrite is not executed because it does not match, and goes to `/shop` in your content directory.

Comment: Thanks, I also tried RewriteRule ^/shop/b2b/something(/)?$ and RewriteRule /shop/b2b/something(/)?$
but it also doesn`t work

Comment: Did you try with the PT flag?  It is seldom used or required.

Comment: yes, I tried with and without the PT flag. Although the PT flag is only relevant for the target or substitution string. So it should have no effect on the segment triggering the rule.